# StreamingSubscriptionConnection.Open hangs for one O365 mailbox

Tags: .net, exchangewebservices

We are using Streaming Events to get notifications from EWS of different users in Office 365.

For this, we have made a subscription manager managing the connections to the different servers. A call to open a subscription looks like this:

```
_Connection = new StreamingSubscriptionConnection(_Service, 30);
// Add connections to the queue
foreach (var subscription in pendingSubscribes)
{
    _Connection.AddSubscription(subscription);
}
if (_Subscriptions.Count > 0) _Connection.Open();
```

This worked like a charm, but right now, the code does not resume over the `Open` call for a certain O365 mailbox. All other tested mailboxes worked.

The Stream has been properly registered:

```
** EwsRequestHttpHeaders **
<Trace Tag="EwsRequestHttpHeaders" Tid="19" Time="2017-05-22 15:26:28Z">
POST /EWS/Exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Accept: text/xml
User-Agent: ExchangeServicesClient/15.00.0913.015
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
X-AnchorMailbox: mail@contoso.onmicrosoft.com
X-PreferServerAffinity: True


</Trace>

** EwsRequest **
<Trace Tag="EwsRequest" Tid="19" Time="2017-05-22 15:26:28Z" Version="15.00.0913.015">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
      <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" />
      <t:ExchangeImpersonation>
        <t:ConnectingSID>
          <t:SmtpAddress>mail@contoso.onmicrosoft.com</t:SmtpAddress>
        </t:ConnectingSID>
      </t:ExchangeImpersonation>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
      <m:Subscribe>
        <m:StreamingSubscriptionRequest>
          <t:FolderIds>
            <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="calendar">
              <t:Mailbox>
                <t:EmailAddress>mail@contoso.onmicrosoft.com</t:EmailAddress>
              </t:Mailbox>
            </t:DistinguishedFolderId>
          </t:FolderIds>
          <t:EventTypes>
            <t:EventType>CreatedEvent</t:EventType>
            <t:EventType>ModifiedEvent</t:EventType>
            <t:EventType>DeletedEvent</t:EventType>
          </t:EventTypes>
        </m:StreamingSubscriptionRequest>
      </m:Subscribe>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
</Trace>

** EwsResponseHttpHeaders **
<Trace Tag="EwsResponseHttpHeaders" Tid="19" Time="2017-05-22 15:26:29Z">
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
request-id: 6f3920a2-9fb3-4717-b966-2861eef559a4
X-CalculatedBETarget: DB5PR02MB1191.eurprd02.prod.outlook.com
X-BackEndHttpStatus: 200
X-FromBackend-ServerAffinity: True
x-EwsHandler: Subscribe
X-DiagInfo: DB5PR02MB1191
X-BEServer: DB5PR02MB1191
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Set-Cookie: exchangecookie=4a58...bf16; expires=Tue, 22-May-2018 15:26:28 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly,X-BackEndOverrideCookie=DB5PR02MB1191.eurprd02.prod.outlook.com~1942062157; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-FEServer: DB6PR0601CA0013
Date: Mon, 22 May 2017 15:26:29 GMT


</Trace>

** EwsResponse **
<Trace Tag="EwsResponse" Tid="19" Time="2017-05-22 15:26:29Z" Version="15.00.0913.015">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
      <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="1" MajorBuildNumber="1101" MinorBuildNumber="19" Version="V2017_04_14" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
      <m:SubscribeResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
        <m:ResponseMessages>
          <m:SubscribeResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
            <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
            <m:SubscriptionId>JwBk...iMM=</m:SubscriptionId>
          </m:SubscribeResponseMessage>
        </m:ResponseMessages>
      </m:SubscribeResponse>
    </s:Body>
  </s:Envelope>
</Trace>
```

Then we open the StreamingConnection. This is how it looks for a working mailbox:

```
** EwsRequestHttpHeaders **
<Trace Tag="EwsRequestHttpHeaders" Tid="19" Time="2017-05-22 15:28:20Z">
POST /EWS/Exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Accept: text/xml
User-Agent: ExchangeServicesClient/15.00.0913.015
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
X-AnchorMailbox: mail@contoso.onmicrosoft.com
X-PreferServerAffinity: True
X-BackEndOverrideCookie:


</Trace>

** EwsRequest **
<Trace Tag="EwsRequest" Tid="19" Time="2017-05-22 15:28:20Z" Version="15.00.0913.015">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
      <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" />
      <t:ExchangeImpersonation>
        <t:ConnectingSID>
          <t:SmtpAddress>mail@contoso.onmicrosoft.com</t:SmtpAddress>
        </t:ConnectingSID>
      </t:ExchangeImpersonation>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
      <m:GetStreamingEvents>
        <m:SubscriptionIds>
          <t:SubscriptionId>JwBk...iMM=</t:SubscriptionId>
        </m:SubscriptionIds>
        <m:ConnectionTimeout>30</m:ConnectionTimeout>
      </m:GetStreamingEvents>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
</Trace>

** EwsResponseHttpHeaders **
<Trace Tag="EwsResponseHttpHeaders" Tid="19" Time="2017-05-22 15:28:21Z">
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
request-id: 25bb05d0-7619-419d-833b-e0b7f3b539c5
X-CalculatedBETarget: DB5PR02MB1191.eurprd02.prod.outlook.com
X-BackEndHttpStatus: 200
X-NoBuffering: 1
X-DiagInfo: DB5PR02MB1191
X-BEServer: DB5PR02MB1191
X-FEServer: HE1P195CA0011
Cache-Control: private
Date: Mon, 22 May 2017 15:28:20 GMT
Set-Cookie: exchangecookie=4a58...bf16; path=/
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET


</Trace>
```

The response body does not come back immediately, because the connection is kept open.

For the non-working mailbox, however, Response Http Headers are not coming back at all.

What can cause this issue? Shouldn't an API return either valid data or an error message?

Comment: Could you just be hitting concurrent connection issues (this is the most common error) eg if you haven't set https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit(v=vs.110).aspx then you won't be able to open more then 2 connections. The other thing i would suggest is you test that mailbox with the EWSeditor https://ewseditor.codeplex.com/

Comment: @GlenScales That was it. Do you know whether there is a maximum number of Exchange Servers a single Office 365 tenant can be part of? Or can I just set the ConnectionLimit to 30k safely?

Comment: If your using impersonation then you shouldn't hit an concurrency issues